# Problem with \b in cyrillic (JavaScript Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, ucp

I have this regex: `(*UCP).*\bпроверка\b.*.` And it works well on the regex101.com (https://regex101.com/r/9elF5c), but not in JavaScript.

```js
const regex = /(*UCP).*\bпроверка\b.*/
console.log(regex.test('а проверка б'))
```

Can someone please explain what the problem is and how to fix it

Comment: In regex101.com you have PCRE flavor selected. If you switch to ECMAScript it doesn't work there, either.

Comment: The problem is most likely that JS doesn't treat Cyrylic letters as word characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `(*UCP)` is a modifier supported by [PCRE](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#pcre).

The error in Javascript is because this syntax does not work `(*` The parenthesis is a special char and the `*` is a quantifier.

If the string should have whitespace boundaries on the left and right:

```
.*(?<!\S)проверка(?!\S).*
```

```js
const regex = /.*(?<!\S)проверка(?!\S).*/
console.log(regex.test('а проверка б'))
```